# Remove all pdf hyperlinks while maintaining hyperref formatting

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, cross-referencing, color

I want to split a `pdflatex` pdf document into two parts. The second part has references to the first part, which are hyperlinks and which I want to remove, **without changing the visual appearance**. So I want the links colored, bordered, same text, font, ..., whatever they look like - I just don't want them active/clickable any more. For example, the `draft` option makes all links appear uncolored.

Is there a quick way to achieve this using `pdflatex`?

I have tried messing with `\pdfstartlink` and `\pdfendlink`, but it seems just redefining those to `{}` makes the pdf arguments following `\pdfstartlink` appear - it works fine otherwise.

MWE with what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=[RGB]{0,0,255}}
\makeatletter
\let\pdfendlink\relax
\let\pdfstartlink\relax
%\let\pdfstartlink\@gobble
%\let\pdfstartlink\@gobbletwo
%\let\pdfstartlink\@gobblethree
%\let\pdfstartlink\@gobblefour
%\def\pdfstartlink#1{}
%\def\pdfstartlink#1#2{}
%\def\pdfstartlink#1#2#3{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    Reference to \ref{Test}.
    \section{Test}
    \label{Test}
\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be related to `\pdfstartlink` being used like this:

```
\pdfstartlink attr{#1}goto name{#2}\relax
```

So I would basically need to `\def` `\pdfstartlink` to take arguments up to the second closed `}` (or the `\relax`), which I find myself unable to do.

Here is a more complicated test case:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\Hy@StartlinkName#1#2{}
\def\close@pdflink{%
    \Hy@endcolorlink
    \Hy@VerboseLinkStop
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \href{X}{Y} \href{X}{Y} \href{X}{Y} \href{X}{Y} \href{X}{Y} \href{X}{Y} \href{X}{Y} \href{X}{Y} \href{X}{Y} \href{X}{Y} \href{X}{Y}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could simply remove the hyperref package and redefine \ref etc. to change colors or add boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly abridged version that also allows for switches (to activate/deactivate the patches):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=[RGB]{0,0,255}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\pdfnolink#1\relax{}% \pdfnolink gobbles everything up to the next \relax
\def\pdfendnolink{}% Just a marker for replacement purposes

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DisableHyperlinks}{%
  \patchcmd{\close@pdflink}{\pdfendlink}{\pdfendnolink}{}{}
  \patchcmd{\Hy@StartlinkName}{\pdfstartlink}{\pdfnolink}{}{}% for references
  \patchcmd{\hyper@linkurl}{\pdfstartlink}{\pdfnolink}{}{}% for \href{http://...}{...}
  \patchcmd{\hyper@linkfile}{\pdfstartlink}{\pdfnolink}{}{}% for \href{XYZ...}{...}
}
\newcommand{\EnableHyperlinks}{%
  \patchcmd{\close@pdflink}{\pdfendnolink}{\pdfendlink}{}{}
  \patchcmd{\Hy@StartlinkName}{\pdfnolink}{\pdfstartlink}{}{}% for references
  \patchcmd{\hyper@linkurl}{\pdfnolink}{\pdfstartlink}{}{}% for \href{http://...}{...}
  \patchcmd{\hyper@linkfile}{\pdfnolink}{\pdfstartlink}{}{}% for \href{XYZ...}{...}
}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\section{Many hyperlinks}\label{Hyperlinks}

Reference to Section~\ref{Hyperlinks}.

\href{http://www.google.com}{Google}

\hrulefill Hyperlinks disabled\hrulefill
% Disable all links
\DisableHyperlinks

Reference to Section~\ref{Hyperlinks}.

\href{http://www.google.com}{Google}

\hrulefill Hyperlinks enabled\hrulefill
%Enable all links
\EnableHyperlinks

Reference to Section~\ref{Hyperlinks}.

\href{http://www.google.com}{Google}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect. The key thing (apart from the switching and patching) that I could not find is `\def\pdfstartlink#1\relax{}` - I came pretty close with `\let\pdfstartlink\relax` and `\def\pdfstartlink#1{}`, but not quite enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The relevant commands for 'plain' links seem to be `\Hy@StartlinkName` and `\close@pdflink`, as far as I've understood `hpdftex.def`, the `pdftex` driver for `hyperref`.

Removing `\pdfstartlink` and `\pdfendlink` preserves the formatting, but disables the clickability.

Note: I don't claim the usability of this procedure for all occurences of links, especially, links from the bookmarks **are not** disabled!

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=[RGB]{0,0,255}}
\makeatletter

\newif\ifdisablelinks
\disablelinkstrue
\ifdisablelinks
\def\Hy@StartlinkName#1#2{%
  % \pdfstartlink attr{#1}goto name{#2}\relax
}

\def\close@pdflink{%
  \Hy@endcolorlink
  \Hy@VerboseLinkStop
  %\pdfendlink
}
\fi

\makeatother
\begin{document}
Reference to \ref{Test}.
\section{Test}
\label{Test}

\clearpage
\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \label{einstein}
\end{equation}
\pdfbookmark{einstein}{Einsteins equation}
\clearpage
In \cref{einstein} we see
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good already. Do you have any idea why it does not work for my extended test case above (the one with the bibliography)? The error message is "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pdf link stack size=10]. \end{document}"

Comment: @bers: It compiles for me, except for the specific bibliography style file (I changed to `unsrt`)

Comment: The bst file is the key point :) I can't pinpoint what part it is, but I guess the problem is that `apsrev4-1` creates doi links, which `unsrt` does not.

Comment: @bers: You changed to `apsrev4-1` -- now I get the error too

Comment: I have minimized it further, a lot.

Comment: @bers: I've no solution for this at the moment other than to edit the `.bst` file and rename it

Comment: See my latest example - it's not related to the `bst` file, the error results from using more than 10 `\href`s in the document.

Answer (score 1):

I extended @Christian Hupfer's solution to this; the idea is principally the same.

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=[RGB]{0,0,255}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\close@pdflink}{\pdfendlink}{}{}{error}

% for references
\patchcmd{\Hy@StartlinkName}{\pdfstartlink attr{#1}goto name{#2}\relax}{}{}{error}

% for \href{http://...}{...}
\patchcmd{\hyper@linkurl}{\pdfstartlink
    attr{%
        \Hy@setpdfborder
        \ifx\@pdfhightlight\@empty
        \else
        /H\@pdfhighlight
        \fi
        \ifx\@urlbordercolor\relax
        \else
        /C[\@urlbordercolor]%
        \fi
    }%
    user{%
        /Subtype/Link%
        \ifHy@pdfa /F 4\fi
        /A<<%
        /Type/Action%
        /S/URI%
        /URI(\Hy@pstringURI)%
        \ifHy@href@ismap
        /IsMap true%
        \fi
        \Hy@href@nextactionraw
        >>%
    }%
    \relax}{}{}{error}

% for \href{XYZ...}{...}
\patchcmd{\hyper@linkfile}{\pdfstartlink
    attr{%
        \Hy@setpdfborder
        \ifx\@pdfhighlight\@empty
        \else
        /H\@pdfhighlight
        \fi
        \ifx\@filebordercolor\relax
        \else
        /C[\@filebordercolor]%
        \fi
    }%
    user {%
        /Subtype/Link%
        \ifHy@pdfa /F 4\fi
        /A<<%
        /F(\Hy@pstringF)%
        /S/GoToR%
        \Hy@SetNewWindow
        \ifx\\#3\\%
        /D[\Hy@href@page\@pdfremotestartview]%
        \else
        /D(\Hy@pstringD)%
        \fi
        \Hy@href@nextactionraw
        >>%
      }%
      \relax}{}{}{error}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Reference to section \ref{Hyperlinks}.

    \section{Many hyperlinks}
    \label{Hyperlinks}

    \href{http://www.google.com}{Google}
    \href{A}{A}
    \href{B}{B}
    \href{C}{C}
    \href{X}{X}
    \href{Y}{Y}
    \href{Z}{Z}
    \href{1}{1}
    \href{2}{2}
    \href{3}{3}
    \href{4}{4}
    \href{5}{5}
\end{document}
```

It may require further extension for other types of links, but so far, I am happy.

Comment: I would generally avoid using such a large patch, as *any* change within the `<search>` part will cause the patch to fail.

Comment: This is certainly true. Luckily, the patch will not fail silently when `hyperref` is updated, as opposed to Christian's solution (which will either silently fail or use outdated code). I am not happy about the long patch, either, so I asked https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286315/remove-all-pdf-hyperlinks-while-maintaining-hyperref-formatting

Comment: "Failing silently" is purely a coder's choice. You can include a `\typeout{Failure}` under `<failure>`, or something else (like `error` in your case, which will cause an error since typesetting is not allowed in the preamble). I usually leave this empty as at the time of presenting the solution, it works, and therefore such messages seem superfluous. However, a more general approach would include something to accommodate all kinds of scenarios down the line...

Comment: Having your solution, I totally agree. Before that, I also saw the choice between duplicating a large chunk of code (as in Christian's approach - the to-keep code) or another large chunk of code (as in my approach - the to-delete code). I usually choose the latter because `\xpatchcmd` has a fall-back mechanismus that a simple redefinition is lacking. But of course, a minimal patch as yours is not to beat.